# Prove that $f_n(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

I am having problems with the following exercise, I am not sure if my procedure is correct.

**Exercise:**

Let
$ \large f_n(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  0 ~~~if~~x = 0  \\
                  \frac{sin(xn)}{xn} ~~~if~~0<x\leq 1
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $

and I need to *prove that $f_n(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.*

Okay so in order for me to show that $f_n(x)$ is discontinous I need to show that  it does not satisfy the following:

For every $\large \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\large \delta > 0$ such that 
$\large \vert \frac{sin(xn)}{xn}\vert < \epsilon$ whenever $\large \vert x\vert<\delta$

I cannot seem to figure out how to show that $f_n(x)$ doesn't satisfy this at $x = 0$. Do I just choose a random $\epsilon$ and then show that I cannot find a $\delta$?

Best regards Husky653

Comment: You need to find an $x\neq 0$ which violates continuity in the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition. Alternatively, take the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f_n(x)$ and show that it's not 0. Also $0>\epsilon$ makes no sense and is incorrect.

Comment: You need to find $x$ so that $|f_n(x) - f_n(0)|>\epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon$. You havent found that yet.

Comment: @John I have edited the question now, but I still don't understand how I choose $\epsilon$. Do I just choose a random one since it has to be true for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$?

Comment: @John, Yes and I have also found the pointwise limit of $f_n$ can I use this?

Comment: Then similarly $\frac{\sin nx}{nx} \to 1$ as $x\to 0$. Thus there are $x_k \to 0$ so that $\frac{\sin nx_k}{nx_k} >\frac 12$ and $x_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.